# Servlet response data for autocomplete

Tags: java, autocomplete

The following code is in PHP.  I want to do the same in Java.  Please tell me how do I generate this type of array or collection in Java.  I need this to response to JSON autocomplete.

```
<?php
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;
$items = array(
 "Peter Pan"=>"peter@pan.de",
 "Molly"=>"molly@yahoo.com",
 "Forneria Marconi"=>"live@japan.jp",
 "Master Sync"=>"205bw@samsung.com",
 "Dr. Tech de Log"=>"g15@logitech.com",
 "Don Corleone"=>"don@vegas.com",
 "Mc Chick"=>"info@donalds.org",
 "Donnie Darko"=>"dd@timeshift.info",
 "Quake The Net"=>"webmaster@quakenet.org",
 "Dr. Write"=>"write@writable.com"
);

$result = array();
foreach ($items as $key=>$value) {
 if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
  array_push($result, array(
   "name" => $key,
   "to" => $value
  ));
 }
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

#### Update:

I want java version of this PHP code because this code is returning in JSON format. In

```
{name=>"Peter Pan",
 to=>"peter@pan.de";
.....}
```

As you see this:-

```
array_push($result, array(
   "name" => $key,
   "to" => $value
  ));
```

Which can be handled by this jQuery code:-

```
$('#inputItem').autocomplete('<c:url value="/json/itemautocomplete.do" />', {
            multiple: true,
            mustMatch: true,
            autoFill: true,
            highlight: false,
            scroll: true,
            dataType: "json",
            parse: function(data){
                var array = new Array();
                for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){

                    array[array.length] = {data: data[i], value: data[i].name, result: data[i].name};
                                        }
                return array;


            }

        });
```

This plugin is available on [this url](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)

I know how to handle JSON data by using `JSONArray` in `$.getJSON` jQuery method. But that thing is not working in this case. I think I need to format my data as I described above in this answer so that this jQuery autocomplete plugin can understand the data. Please tell me how can I get this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you would use a [`Map<String, String>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

```
Map<String, String> items = new HashMap<String, String>();
items.put("Peter Pan", "peter@pan.de");

String petersAddress = items.get("Peter Pan");
```

You can iterate through the keyset:

```
for ( String key : items.keySet() ) {
  if ( key.toLowerCase().startsWith(input) ) {
     //add to list of potential matches
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for ur support.

I have handled the data by using this code:-
In Servlet:-

```
LinkedList arr = new LinkedList();
arr.add("Peter Pan <peter@pan.de>");
arr.add("Molly <molly@yahoo.com>");
arr.add("Forneria Marconi <live@japan.jp>");

Iterator iter = arr.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
     out.println(iter.next());
}
```

In JQuery:-

```
function itemAutocomplete(){
        $('#inputItem').autocomplete('<c:url value="/json/itemautocomplete.do?mi=' + $('#sltMainItem').val() + '&si=' + $('#sltSubItem').val() + '" />', {
            json: true
        });
    }
```

Thanks for being here for me
Shams